# In Oblivion is there a 1 to 1 relationship between skill advances and stats at level up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I know that how many point you can add to your attributes depends on how you leveled up your skills during that level but if I level up 5 strength skills will I get +5 to strength or is it not 1 to 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's *sort* of how it works. From the [Oblivion FAQ](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Leveling):

> When you level you get to raise the values of three attributes. The amount you can raise an attribute by depends on how many skill points you have gained in skills governed by this attribute (major and minor).
>
> 0 skill points grants a +1 bonus
> 1-4 skill points grants a +2 bonus
> 5-7 skill points grants a +3 bonus
> 8-9 skill points grants a +4 bonus
> 10 or more skill points grants a +5 bonus
>
> It is never possible to gain more than a +5 attribute bonus when leveling up. Attribute bonuses not used at one level (or surplus points past 10 in the skills governed by an attribute) do not roll over to the next level.
>
> For example, say a character has the following major skills (seven in total, listed by attribute):
>
> Agility: None
> Endurance: Armorer
> Intelligence: Conjuration; Mysticism
> Personality: Illusion
> Speed: None
> Strength: Blade
> Willpower: Destruction; Restoration
>
> Since his previous level-up he has increased some skills (see below, increase in parenthesis after each skill). When he acquired the 10th increase in a major skill, he qualified for a level-up. The attributes offered to him would be as listed to the right in the examples below.
>
> **Example 1**
> Attribute Skill Increases Bonus
> Agility Security (2) +2
> Endurance None +1
> Intelligence Alchemy (10), Conjuration (1), Mysticism (1) +5
> Personality None +1
> Speed Athletics (5), Acrobatics (5) +5
> Strength Blade (4), Blunt (4) +4
> Willpower Destruction (4) +2
>
> For those concerned with over-leveling or skill management this is not a "perfect" level-up. An example of a 5/5/5 increase (as mentioned in Efficient Leveling) for this character could be:
>
> **Example 2**
> Attribute Skill Increases Bonus
> Agility None +1
> Endurance None +1
> Intelligence None +1
> Personality Illusion (6), Mercantile (4) +5
> Speed Athletics (5), Acrobatics (3), Light Armor (2) +5
> Strength None +1
> Willpower Destruction (4), Alteration (6) +5
>
> Here only 3 attributes have more than the minimum +1 modifier, and they all get the maximum +5. Illusion and Destruction are the only major skills that have been increased (4+6=10), along with a total of 20 minor skills. No skills have been over leveled. Note that the last one of the increased skills has to be a major skill.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily one-to-one. Check out the following, helpful Wiki page on the subject. It took me a while to understand it all, but it's pretty straightforward once you "get it".

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Leveling